# z-index not working on video in android

Tags: html, video, z-index

I have some problems on HTML5 video when I make a page not app working on mobile. I want to put some words on video when video plays, but it seems the z-index not working on video. This problem have troubles me a long time, and I have searched on google, stackoverflow and css-tricks, not finding the right answer.

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="danmu">小苹果小苹果小苹果</div>
    <video id="video" controls="controls">
        <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />             
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
#video{width:100%;position: relative;}      
#danmu{position: absolute;width: 100%;left:0;top:0;color:red;z-index:10;}
#main_container { float: left; position: fixed; left:0; top:0;width:100%;}
```

Comment: I have the same problem when show in android browsers, it's ok in pc browsers.

Comment: I have a similar problem when the PM ask me to display a share hover over video, it works fine on iOS, but not working on Android Wechat, no matter how you setup the z-index attribute.
But I discover a tricky way, when I need to display the share hover, I add hidden to the video tag, so that I won't mess up with the view.

Comment: I also have this problem only on Android Weixin/QQ browser, and it works perfectly on iOS and normal browsers. Do you have a better solution except to hide the video ?